# How do I access this environment variable in the windows git bash shell

Tags: windows, bash, shell, git, git-bash

I am trying to configure my *windows portable git bash shell*.  When I execute `env` I get:

```
ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\WinAnt
PORTABLEAPPS.COMVIDEOS:FORWARDSLASH=H:/Documents/Videos
VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
PORTABLEAPPS.COMLOCALEWINNAME=LANG_ENGLISH
PAL:LASTPORTABLEAPPSBASEDIR:DOUBLEBACKSLASH=H:
PAL:DRIVELETTER=H   **** this is the variable I am after  ******
PAL:APPDIR=H:\PortableApps\GitPortable\App
TEMP=/tmp
```

The variable I am trying to reference is `PAL:DRIVELETTER=H`.  I want to use this set my path in my `.bash_profile` script.  This is all on a USB stick and the drive letter will of course change from time to time.

I have tried echoing:

```
$PAL:DRIVELETTER
${PAL:DRIVELETTER}
```

and numerous other things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `PAL:DRIVELETTER` is not a valid variable name in bash. Only alphanumeric and underscore are allowed. From the bash man page:

> **DEFINITIONS**
>
> ...
>
> > **name**   A *word* consisting only of alphanumeric characters and underscores, and beginning with an alphabetic character or an underscore.  Also referred to as an **identifier**.

To get the value:

```
pal_driveletter=$(env |grep "^PAL:DRIVELETTER=" | cut -d= -f2-)
```